# Can you prove Fatou's lemma for conditional expectations by that of the normal version?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

I'd like to discuss proofs of [Fatou's lemma for conditional expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma#Fatou%27s_lemma_for_conditional_expectations).

It can be proved by almost the same idea for normal version, i.e., by applying the monotone convergence theorem for conditional expectations for $\inf_{k \geq n} X_k$. You can review its detail by the link above toward Wikipedia.

Then, I wonder how we can prove Fatou's lemma for conditional expectations, not using the monotone convergence theorem for conditional expectations, but using [Fatou's lemma of the normal version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma#Standard_statement). Do you know this proof?

Letting
\[
N = \left\{ E[\liminf_{n \to  \infty} X_n | \mathcal{G}] > \liminf_{n \to \infty} E[X_n | \mathcal{G}] \right\},
\]
I tried to prove $P(N) = 0$ by applying Fatou's lemma for $\{ E[X_n | \mathcal{G}] \}$ and $\{ X_n \}$, but failed. It seemed that simple ideas didn't work well.

I consulted my textbooks for probability theory and related fields and I found only the same proof above.

Kindly please note that our definition of conditional expectations is [a standard one characterized by integrals and measurableness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_sub-%CF%83-algebra). If we define conditional probabilities first and then introduce conditional expectations by integrals with them, Fatou's lemma for conditional expectations is proved by that of the normal version, obviously. I hope you will tell me a connection between the standard definition of conditional expectations and Fatou's lemma of the normal version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little late to the party but the general idea is for all $G \in \mathcal G$
$$\int_G E[X_n | \mathcal G]dP = \int_G X_n dP $$
I think you were on the right track with your $N$ set. Let $\varepsilon>0$.
$$N = \{E[\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n|\mathcal G] > \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} E[X_n | \mathcal G] + \varepsilon\} \in \mathcal G $$
$$\implies E[\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n | \mathcal G] > E[X_n| \mathcal G] + \varepsilon \textrm{ infinitely often on }N $$
Let $\{X_{n_k}\}$ be the subsequence where this happens
$$\implies E[\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n|\mathcal G] > E[X_{n_k} | \mathcal G] + \varepsilon \textrm{ on }N$$
$$\implies \int_N E[\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n|\mathcal G]dP \geq \varepsilon P(N)+ \int_N E[X_{n_k} | \mathcal G]dP  $$
Now use the defining relation on both sides
$$\implies \int_N \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n dP \geq \varepsilon P(N) +\int_N X_{n_k} dP$$
And Fatou's Lemma on the LHS
$$\implies \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty }\int_N X_n dP \geq \varepsilon P(N) + \int_N X_{n_k} dP$$
Since the righthand is a subsequence, its liminf cannot be smaller, and since the inequality held for all $k$ we can take it.
$$\implies \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty }\int_N X_n dP \geq \varepsilon P(N) + \liminf_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_N X_{n_k} dP \geq  \varepsilon P(N) +\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_N X_n dP $$
Now we have a squeeze, so subtract the integral from the outermost sides
$$0 \geq \varepsilon P(N) \geq 0 $$
$$\implies P(N) = 0 $$
And since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary
$$E[\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n |\mathcal G] \overset{a.s.}{\leq} \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} E[X_n | \mathcal G] $$
I think the connection between them is all in the defining relation. Fatou's Lemma essentially tells us
$$\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_\Omega  f_n d\mu \geq \int_\Omega\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}  f_n d\mu  $$
Which is the same as saying for all $\varepsilon>0$
$$\int_\Omega  f_n d\mu  \not \leq \varepsilon +\int_\Omega\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}  f_n d\mu  \textrm{  infinitely often } $$

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear explanation. This does solve my question. The characteristic of Fatou's lemma by i.o. that you mentioned is great.